# Magento: How do I move the product options to a tab in the 'modern theme'?

Tags: magento

I would like to move the configurable product options and the custom product options into the first tab of the 'Modern Theme'.

Ideally with the prices updating when I change options.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I cheated. In prototype on view.phtml I hid my product options block during page load, then on DOM loaded I appendchilded it to the description div in the tabs then unhid it. This works well as the page top - above the fold - loads cleanly and the options drop in later without the visitor being aware that something has gone on.